# Django redirecting everything to homepage

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck with a Django project, I tried to add another app called login to make a login page but for some reason the page just redirects to the homepage except for the admin page

For example: 127.0.0.1:8000 will go to the homepage but 127.0.0.1:8000/login will also display the homepage even though I linked another template to it.

Here is my code:

main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('portal.urls')),
    url(r'^login/', include('login.urls')),
]
```

login urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', views.index, name="login"),
]
```

login views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'login/login.html')
```

portal urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name="portal"),
]
```

Comment: Please show your `portal/urls.py` file.

Comment: Change the order of the third and second lines in your main `urls.py`.

Comment: @knbk I edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 2 problems here:

1. As @DanielRoseman mentioned above, the regular expression `^` matches anything, so you should change it to `^$`.
2. When you use an `include`,  the rest of the path after what the `include` matched is passed to the included pattern. You’ll want to use `^$` in your login urls.py too.

Comment: Thanks!

This was the answer.
Also thanks to @danielRoseman for the same answer

Answer (score 4):

You don't terminate the portal index URL, so it matches everything. It should be:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name="portal"),
```

Comment: If I do that i get this error:


Using the URLconf defined in virt.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, 
in this order:

^admin/

^login/

^$

The current URL, login, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Do you need any other file to figure this out?

Comment: Your login URL is itself being included under /login. So the full URL will be /login/login, which almost certainly isn't what you want. You probably need to use `'^$'` in the login urls.py like you do in the portal one.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if the regex is login/$ but you enter http ://server/login, then it won't match wheras http://server/login/ will.
You could try changing the regex to login/*$, which will match any number (even zero) / on the end of the url.

So http: //server/login, http: //server/login/, http: //server/login//// would all match.

Or if you want to be specific, login/{0,1}$ might work (though that regex syntax is from memory!)

Comment: Django has an `APPEND_SLASH` setting that is set by default, which will redirect `/login` to `/login/` if the first doesn't match, so this is usually unnecessary. If you need it, you can use `^login/?$` to match one or zero slashes.